# Location of Microphone input?

Tags: 14.04, microphone

I am trying to generate data for cryptopurposes in a similar fashion to Random.org except locally so the data isn't passed over the Internet.

I found this guide:
http://openfortress.org/cryptodoc/random/

However, when I use "rec" it doesn't work because "/dev/dsp" has long been depreciated.

The command I'm running is:

```
rec -c 1 -d /dev/dsp -r 8000 -t wav -e signed-integer w  - | ./noise-filter >bits
```

Would this work as long as I change the input device to where ever the Microphone input is? If so, where is that? (I'm running 14.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such device these days.  I believe what you want is:

```
arecord -f S16_LE | ./noise-filter > bits
```

Comment: alsa to the rescue! +1

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. This worked with one minor modification:
    `arecord -t raw -f S16_LE | ./noise-filter > bits`

Without "-t raw" it throws this error: `Could not skip header of WAV file.`

Comment: @PopSmith, odd... the -t wav switch in your original command seems to be request wav instead of raw.